# Windows 7 - right-click in Explorer doesn't select first

Tags: windows-7, right-click

When I'm using Windows Explorer on Windows 7, I'll move my mouse over a folder or file in the pane on the right then right-click. But instead of getting the context menu for the thing I'm hovering over it gives me the context menu of the containing folder. I have to left-click to select the item first then right-click to get its context menu.

Vista worked the way I liked, I only noticed this change when upgrading to Windows 7. Is there a way to get back to the old way of just right-clicking instead of select then right-click?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right-click the filename, not anything else.

[image: Like so]

Comment: Good to know. I never even tried over the file's name since I usually have my mouse off to the side so it doesn't obscure the text. Right-clicking over Date Modified, File Type, etc. also has the proper behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking on the web for a solution but as BloodPhilia mentionned, it seems to have no tweak to enable that.

Please read this [little thread](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/89158-right-click-select-doesnt-seem-work-right.html) ...